# Is there any way to avoid using wait and sleep in selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, sleep

Is there any way to avoid using `driver.wait or driver.sleep` commands?

Something like `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000)` to be used as a general timeout until the element is located?

I am new in automatic testing and coding :)

Comment: I managed to make a "detour" with the method bellow to be used in a general specs, but your answer definitely helped, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can set-up explicit and implicit waits in Selenium.

An example of an explicit wait i.e. wait explicitly for a particular element to appear:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
});
```

An example of an implicit wait (i.e. wait an arbitrary amount of time) is:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
IWebElement myDynamicElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
```

See [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By locator));
```

Waits for a minute for the element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answers. I managed to make a "detour" with the following:

```
function findClickElem(locator, path,  timeout) {

            driver.wait(generalspecs.getSpecs().until.elementLocated(generalspecs.getSpecs().By[locator](path)), timeout).then(function(elem){
                if(elem){
                    elem.click();
                }else{
                    console.log('no element!');
                }
            });
        }
```

Just added to the generalspecs and gets called each time i use a wait and clicks the element.

```
findClickElem("xpath" ,"//li[contains(@class, 'classCustom1')]", 15000);
```